# BIO_write() is not writing to the file when using BIO_f_base64()

Tags: c++, openssl

I am trying to learn OPENSSL and following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxAdd03wyUo&t=612s). I have written following code to read from a file and write the encoded form in another file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 512

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BIO* bio_out = nullptr;
    BIO* bio_in = nullptr;
    BIO* bio_b64 = nullptr;
    int in_byte, out_byte;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::memset(buffer, '\0', MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: bio_b64_encode <source-read> <encoded-write>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    bio_in = BIO_new_file(argv[1], "r");
    bio_out = BIO_new_file(argv[2], "wb");
    bio_b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_push(bio_b64, bio_out);

    in_byte = BIO_read(bio_in, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while (in_byte > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Read " << in_byte << " bytes.\n";
        out_byte = BIO_write(bio_b64, buffer, in_byte);
        std::cout << "Wrote " << out_byte << " bytes.\n";
        if (in_byte != out_byte)
        {
            std::cout << "In bytes: " << in_byte << "and Out bytes: " << out_byte << " are not equal.\n";
            BIO_free(bio_in);
            BIO_free(bio_out);
            return 1;
        }
        in_byte = BIO_read(bio_in, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    BIO_free(bio_in);
    BIO_free_all(bio_b64);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code reads properly from the input file given in `argv[1]` and tries to write to `argv[2]` but when I open the output file, it is empty but it should have the encoded text from the input file.

the output of the above program when I run `./bio_b64_encode in.txt out.txt` is

```
Read 22 bytes.
Wrote 22 bytes.
```

but the output file is empty. If I remove the encoding constraints and try to simply write whatever I read from input file (the code is below), it works properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 512

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BIO* bio_out = nullptr;
    BIO* bio_in = nullptr;
    BIO* bio_b64 = nullptr;
    int in_byte, out_byte;
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
    std::memset(buffer, '\0', MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: bio_write <file-read> <file-write>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    bio_in = BIO_new_file(argv[1], "r");
    bio_out = BIO_new_file(argv[2], "w");

    in_byte = BIO_read(bio_in, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    while (in_byte > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Read " << in_byte << " bytes.\n";
        out_byte = BIO_write(bio_out, buffer, in_byte);
        std::cout << "Wrote " << out_byte << " bytes.\n";
        if (in_byte != out_byte)
        {
            std::cout << "In bytes: " << in_byte << "and Out bytes: " << out_byte << " are not equal.\n";
            BIO_free(bio_in);
            BIO_free(bio_out);
            return 1;
        }
        in_byte = BIO_read(bio_in, buffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
    }

    BIO_free(bio_in);
    BIO_free_all(bio_out);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to figure out what am I missing here.

Comment: You need to do a `BIO_flush()` when you are finished writing when using `BIO_f_base64`

Comment: Did you try reading `BIO_f_base64`'s documentation? I was not familiar with it, so I looked it up. Granted, it required reading a few paragraph's into its description, before I read the answer, but this is clearly documented.

Comment: @President James K. Polk This was helpful. Thanks.